# Can't access object variable starting with http

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript

I have a JSON object called profile that I use in my application which I can access in my html as follows:

`<pre>{{ profile | json }}</pre>`

This gives me the following result on my screen (values omitted):

```
{
    "sub": "Test",
    "name": "Test",
    "nickname": "Test",
    "picture": "Test",
    "updated_at": "2017-07-05T03:34:49.038Z",
    "http://test.com/roles": [
        "admin",
        "guest"
    ]
}
```

I can access all of the variables as follows:

`<h3 class="name">{{ profile?.name }}</h3>`

But where I have trouble is accessing the variable that begins with http. If I try:

`<h3 class="name">{{ profile?.http://test.com/roles }}</h3>`

I get unexpected token errors.

I am unable to change the name of this variable is there some other way I can access it.

Thank you,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Similar to JavaScript, you need to use the bracket notation for object properties that do not have valid [identifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Identifier) names:

```
<h3 class="name">{{ profile ? profile['http://test.com/roles'] : '' }}</h3>
```

Unfortunately, the bracket notation does not support the safe navigation operator (`?`), so you'll have to use a ternary operator instead.

Comment: Hey there,

When I try in this format i get the following error:

Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: Parser Error: Conditional expression profile?['http://test.com/roles'] requires all 3 expressions at the end of the expression

It also gives me a flag in my editor indicating : is expected.

Comment: My bad. Elvis operator is not supported on bracket notation. Will update my answer.